# Retrieving one row no duplicates MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I'm new to mySQL and Please require help. I have a column sales_flat_order that saves orders from several customers and also sales_flat_order_status_history table that saves comments on each order (like pending, verified, complete, etc). I'm trying to merge these two tables but only return the order number where I pick only the min(status) that is verified. However when I run my code I get duplicates Please I need help. See my code below. Please help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sales_flat_order.customer_id,  
MIN(sales_flat_order_status_history.entity_id) AS  
entity_id,sales_flat_order_status_history.parent_id,
sales_flat_order_status_history.created_at AS order_date 
FROM sales_flat_order LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_status_history 
ON sales_flat_order_status_history.parent_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_id FROM sales_flat_order  
       LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_status_history ON 
sales_flat_order_status_history.parent_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id
       WHERE sales_flat_order.created_at < '2013-11-30 23:00:00') AS oo ON   
oo.customer_id=sales_flat_order.customer_id
WHERE ((sales_flat_order_status_history.status LIKE '%verified%' AND  
sales_flat_order.created_at > '2013-11-01 00:00:00')
OR (sales_flat_order.status LIKE '%complete%' AND sales_flat_order.created_at < '2013- 11-01 00:00:00')) 
AND sales_flat_order_status_history.created_at >= '2013-11-30 23:00:00'
AND sales_flat_order_status_history.created_at <= '2013-12-31 22:59:59'  
AND sales_flat_order.customer_id IS NOT NULL 
AND oo.customer_id IS NULL
GROUP BY sales_flat_order.entity_id
```

Comment: that's not your problem I guess but you have a space after '2013- ' in one of your dates

Comment: you might end up with duplicates if either of the column values are different.

Comment: That's not the problem because it's not really like that in my code.

Comment: Yes the values are different but is it possible to get the minimum of the primary key which is the entity_id.